# remove duplicated rows based on ID within string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to remove duplicates (and keep the first duplicate only) based on the number that follows `GeneID:` in the rows of my input. I only know how to filter by column: `awk '!seen[$3]++'`but that does not work here.

Input (tab separated):

```
 Gene1 mRNA ID=rna74353;Parent=gene38534;Dbxref=GeneID:109200613;Genbank:XM_019356191.2,Genbank:XM_025904163.1
 Gene2 mRNA ID=rna74354;Parent=gene38534;Dbxref=GeneID:109200613;Genbank:XM_019356192.2,Genbank:XM_025904163.2
 Gene3 mRNA ID=rna74355;Parent=gene38534;Dbxref=GeneID:109200614;Genbank:XM_019356193.2,Genbank:XM_025904163.3
 Gene4 mRNA ID=rna74356;Parent=gene38534;Dbxref=GeneID:109200615;Genbank:XM_019356194.2,Genbank:XM_025904163.4
```

out:

```
 Gene1 mRNA ID=rna74353;Parent=gene38534;Dbxref=GeneID:109200613;Genbank:XM_019356191.2,Genbank:XM_025904163.1
 Gene3 mRNA ID=rna74355;Parent=gene38534;Dbxref=GeneID:109200614;Genbank:XM_019356193.2,Genbank:XM_025904163.3
 Gene4 mRNA ID=rna7435;Parent=gene38534;Dbxref=GeneID:109200615;Genbank:XM_019356194.2,Genbank:XM_025904163.4
```

Comment: What is the real expected output? I guess there must be one `Gene1 mRNA GeneID:109200614;Genbank:XM_019356193.2`, not two.

Comment: Sorry, updated input

Answer (score 1):

Filtering out duplicates by `GeneID`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }{ f3=$3; sub(";.*", "", f3) }!a[f3]++' test.txt
```

Details:

- `FS=OFS="\t"` - input/output field separator
- `f3=$3` - copy the 3rd field value into variable `f3`
- `sub(";.*", "", f3)` - remove all chars following `;` from `f3` value (to get only GeneID number with prefix)
- `!a[f3]++` - print record ON unique occurrence of the crucial variable `f3`

The output:

```
Gene1   mRNA    GeneID:109200613;Genbank:XM_019356191.2
Gene1   mRNA    GeneID:109200614;Genbank:XM_019356193.2
Gene1   mRNA    GeneID:109200615;Genbank:XM_019356193.2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a boring way to do this and a less boring way to do this:

- **`sort`**: sort the file uniquely based on the second column where the <semi-colon>-character (`;`) is the delimiter:

  ```
  $ sort -u -d; -k1,1
  ```

  This method has the following restrictions:

  - the full substring before the `GeneID` always has to be identical
  - it reorders the output
- **`awk`**: this is another boring way. Assume that the <semi-colon>-character and <colon> character are field separators, then you only need to check if you have seen field 2:

  ```
   $ awk -F'[:;]' '!seen[$2]++'
  ```
- **`awk`**: this is the more interesting way. Assume your file has the following format

  ```
  label1 key1:value1;key2:value2;key3:value3
  label2 key1:value1;key2:value2;key3:value3
  ```

  of which you know that:

  - `label`,`key` and `value` are any string that do not contain ':' or ';'
  - key-value pairs do not need to appear in the same order. I.e. `key2` of `label1` could be `key1` of `label2`.

  The trick here is to extract the key you are interested in:

  ```
  awk -v key="GeneID" '{ match($0,key ":[^:;]*");
                         value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                       }
                       !seen[value]++' file
  ```

Comment: I think you'd need GNU sort for `-s` to guarantee to keep the **first** duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a custom field separator:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]:;]+' '!seen[$4]++' file > newfile
```

The `[[:space:]:;]+` pattern matches one or more (`+`) whitespace (`[:space:]`), `;` or `:` chars. The ID is in Field 4 now, hence `'!seen[$4]++'` is  used.

Output:

```
Gene1   mRNA    GeneID:109200613;Genbank:XM_019356191.2
Gene3   mRNA    GeneID:109200614;Genbank:XM_019356193.2
Gene4   mRNA    GeneID:109200615;Genbank:XM_019356193.2
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/KM2UK9).

Comment: @user2300940 So, I guess my solution still works as expected. I only changed the link to an online demo with new output (containing tabs).